# Why does MSI afterburner grey out the values for voltage, Temp, Core clock, memory clock etc

Tags: graphics-card, gpu, amd-radeon, amd-graphics-card, msi-afterburner

Why does MSI afterburner greyed out the values for voltage, Temp, Core clock, memory clock etc.

All these features are disabled.

I have one AMD Radeon R9 Fury Nano Graphic card with the newest AMD Drivers.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You ran the application as an Administrator?

Comment: Core Clock and Memory Clock do not look disabled. You cannot adjust those settings?

Comment: Yes. the aplication was run as adminstrator. i need to adjust these settings. how i can do it? i have installed the last version of afterburner 4.4. and  there is the same problem

Comment: Those are advanced features and by default are disabled.  Show the configuration screen for the application with which options you have enabled, disabled, and not configured

Comment: Is your cable plugged into your video card or your motherboard? It should be plugged into your video card.

Comment: @Stoyan Which comment helped you resolve the issue?

Answer (score 2):

Change the theme of MSI Afterburner. I had the same problem with a GTX 960 and that fixed it. Everything is now useable.

Answer (score 2):

You have to run an application or game which uses your amd graphics card. I had this same issue so just run an application and open afterburner then it will display the values...

Answer (score 1):

Most probably the issue is with MSI's version. I would highly recommend the latest beta. I had the same issue with 4.3.0, upgraded to 4.4.0 and the issue was solved